# How to unit test code inside Response.OnCompleted() in a finally block

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

### The code under test

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromBody] object request)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok("Okay Message");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, FormProblemDetails(ex, StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError));
    }
    finally
    {
        Response.OnCompleted(async () =>
        {
            if (Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
            {
                // unit test this method.
                await DoSomeWork();
            }
        });
    }
}

private async Task DoSomeWork()
{
  // unit test the code present here.
}
```

### The related unit test

```
//Arrange;

var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = "somedummytoken";
httpContext.Response.**OnCompleted**(null);


MyController controller = new MyController()
{
    ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() { HttpContext = httpContext }
};
```

I want to unit the code inside `Response.OnCompleted` delegate. Currently, `OnCompleted` callback won't getting called in unit test.
Can someone help me to know how to manually trigger `OnCompleted` delegate?

Comment: In the question title you are talking about unit testing. But you have tagged your question with [tag:integration-testing]. Which one are we talking about here?

Comment: @PeterCsala , corrected the tag. I want to unit test the code inside Response.OnCompleted(). please suggest..

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? Whether the `DoSomeWork` has been called or not?

Comment: @PeterCsala yes, I want to unit test the code of private method DoSomeWork().

Answer (score 0):

Long story short you can't.

The `OnCompleted` (or the `OnStarting`) delegates (*not events*) are called by the ASP.NET Core runtime. Which is obviously not available in a unit test. And you can not really mimic it inside a unit test.

**If they were** events then you could [moq's `Raise`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#events) to do something like this

```
responseMock.Raise(r => r.OnCompleted += null, EventArgs.Empty)
```

So, if you need to test this code I would suggest to perform integration testing. There you could assess the side effect of the `DoSomeWork`.